# Asignar una casilla de ajedrez dadas dos posiciones

Tags: python

https://www.aceptaelreto.com/problem/statement.php?id=481&cat=115

Hola, fui a practicar este problema sencillo e hice este código:

```
x, y = input("").split()
ejex = ["h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
for i in ejex:
    if ejex.index(i) == int(x) - 1:
        x = i
print("{}{}".format(x, y))
```

El problema es que tengo este código de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ajedrez.py", line 4, in <module>
    if ejex.index(i) == int(x) - 1:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas intentando hacer operaciones entre diferentes tipos, ya que x e y son strings. Despues de hacer el split, puedes convertir esos string en enteros.

El siguiente codigo funciona correctamente:

```
x, y = raw_input("").split(" ") # Ingresar los numeros separados con un espacio. No tiene manejo de excepciones
xInt = int(x)
yInt = int(y)

ejex = ["h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]

for i in ejex:
    if ejex.index(i) == xInt - 1:
        xInt = i

print("{}{}".format(xInt, yInt))
```

Dejo un enlace con el codigo para verificar el funcionamiento:
https://repl.it/@GabrielMoreyra/AjedrezAceptaElReto

Comment: Me ha servido, gracias. En la línea 8 en lugar de int(x) puse xInt, y funcionó perfectamente ^^

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de que tienes que convertir a entero los datos `x` e `y` tras leerlos con `input()`, entiendo que lo que necesitas hacer después es convertir la `x` en una de las letras contenidas en `["h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]` y que esa es la misión de este bucle:

```
for i in ejex:
    if ejex.index(i) == int(x) - 1:
        x = i
```

No obstante no entiendo por qué hacerlo de forma tan retorcida, ya que `ejex[x-1]` da exactamente el mismo resultado (si `x` es entera).

Propongo por tanto este código alternativo:

```
x, y = input("").split()
x, y = int(x), int(y)

ejex = ["h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
letra = ejex[x-1]
print("{}{}".format(letra, y))
```